# Using multi capabilities is throwing error

Tags: protractor, browserstack

I want to run my tests on multiple browsers and I am using the multi capabilities option to run my protractor tests in browser-stack.

Here is my protractor config file I am using

```
exports.config = {
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  commonCapabilities: {
    browserstackUser: browserstackCredentials.user,
    browserstackKey: browserstackCredentials.key,
    'browserstack.debug': true,
    'browserstack.local': true
  },

  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    os: 'Windows',
    os_version: '10'

  }, {
    os: 'OS X',
    os_version: 'High Sierra',
    browserName: 'Safari'

  }],
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  directConnect: false,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  framework: 'jasmine'
}
```

I get the below error when I run tests with these config. Below is the error I get :

> [chrome #01-0] [13:46:12] E/local - Error code: 135
>   [chrome #01-0] [13:46:12] E/local - Error message: No update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
>   [chrome #01-0] [13:46:12] E/local - Error: No update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
>   [chrome #01-0]     at Local.addDefaultBinaryLocs_ (/home/travis/build/xxx/xxx/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/local.js:39:23)
>   [chrome #01-0]     at Local.setupDriverEnv (/home/travis/build/xxx/xxx/node_modules/protractor/built/driver.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `webdriver-manager update` ?

Comment: are you able to run these tests locally? on chrome and firefox/safari?

Comment: Hi , I am unable to run the tests locally. I get the same error.

Comment: I tried to update webdriver-manager after this error. But everytime I use multi caps I get this error.

Comment: Hi , did you get a chance to review my comment ? If not could you please ? Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, The problem is with the file update-config.json 
  The behavior of protractor is to first locate the update-config.json file which contains the information of chrome/firefox driver. If the same file is not located then Protractor throw the same error as you mentioned.

Fix - Go to the path node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\bin which contains webdriver-manager file.

```
  use >> node webdriver-manager update
```

This command will create selenium folder under the path " your project directory\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager.
Once selenium folder is created then it will have version of chrome/gecko drivers and update-config.json file.

Comment: Hi , thank you for the recommendations. I tried updating the webdriver-manager but it did not help. Also , I get this error only when I use multi caps not when I have single capabilities.

Comment: Hi , did you get a chance to review my comment ? If not could you please ? Thanks

Comment: I resolved the same issue with the solution i mentioned. If you could share some sample script with the configuration that doesn't work then i would be able to figure out the issue after testing the same on my machine.